# Method remove(Object o) is not supported by this implementation In DataBindingLazyMetaPropertyMap

Tags: java, dictionary, grails

In DataBindingLazyMetaPropertyMap in grails "put, get" method does work but remove doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea as well as solution for this???

My Code:

```
   def mapObj = [age:"20",location:"earth"] 
   mapObj.put("name","test");  // inserts the data in mapObj with key = "name" 

   mapObj.get("name"); // returns the value of the mapObj with key = "name" 

   mapObj.remove("name"); // removes the key value pair from mapObj with key = "name"
```

the class of the mapObj is java.util.LinkedHashMap

Until now everythig is working fine.

```
 mapObj = domainObj.properties
```

Converts the class of the mapObj to DataBindingLazyMetaPropertyMap

```
mapObj.put("name","test"); // inserts the data in mapObj with key "name" 

mapObj.get("name"); // returns the value of the mapObj with key "name" 

mapObj.remove("name"); // returns error Method remove(Object o) is not supported by this implementation
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are unsure check what data type it is :

```
mapObj = domainObj.properties
println "object is now ${mapObj.getClass()}"
```

In groovy sometimes things become the real object so you need to take a copy of it instead. Compare above to for example:

```
mapObj = domainObj.properties.clone()
```

**e2A**

So your comment suggests it can't be cloned.

Please review this link

```
http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/properties.html

def b = new Book(title: "The Shining")
b.properties = params
b.save()
```

No where have I ever used properties to query / grab a domain object map **always to set it's values**

You will need to either write a HQL query that does a `select new map(e.a as a, e.b as b) from A blah`  to return you a flat map

or Introduce a new function in your domain class

```
Class Example
  String a
  String b

def loadValues() {
  Map map = [:]
  map.a=this.a
  map.b=this.ba
  return map
 }
}
```

now call

```
mapObj = domainObj.loadValues()
```

Which returns a flat map of your objects

Also refer to `implements cloneable`

Comment: use of the .clone() function resulted in the CloneNotSupportedException.